# Shortcut based on modes (Vertex, Edge, Poly)

Tags: modeling

When in Edit Mode is it possible to have the same shortcut doing different operations based on the mode we are in (vertex, edge, poly).

for example, the "F" key is "fill" when in edge-mode but "flip normal" when in poly-mode.

Thank you

Comment: In 2.8 this is partially the case since depending on selection mode right click menu contents will be different. I can't say this is intuitive though. As to your question it might be clearer if you mention why you want to do that

Comment: so I can use less shortcuts, is more intuitive and efficient in this way. I haven't seen anything in Preference>Keymap , so I assume it can't be done, unless someone wants develop this feature.

Comment: Although the right-click menu that appear in edit mode is context sensitive to the selection mode....so I guess it could be done with some scripting.